# Why are lumped elements suggested for modeling RF circuits

Tags: rf

I'm currently trying to convert S-parameters to time domain. In my search I came across this quote [here](http://www.edaboard.com/thread40057.html)

> If your s2p file is the s parameters of a passive circuit, you have to
>   convert it to y or z parameters and then implement this two port y
>   parameters by lumped elements at the center frequency of your design.
>   so around the center frequency your lumped model is valid and you can
>   use this lumped model in time domain.
>
> for increasing the frequency range of validity, you have to use an
>   optmizer to match the s parameters of lumped network to your s2p file
>   over the desired frequency range.

I realize that I've seen in several other places (especially in modelling with ADS) that they suggest using lumped elements as a basis for understanding. Why do they suggest lumped elements?

Comment: Why are lumped elements assumed at all (in other cases; in general)? What's the alternative? Assuming lumped elements means you have to solve (only) a system of **N ordinary** differential equations. Not assuming lumped elements means you have to solve **partial** differential equations (Maxwell's Eqs) for the  **continuous space** which is much more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematics of distributed circuit design becomes too complicated. Equations and tables for design of lumped element circuits are well understood. Two port network abcd matrices can even be used to calculate frequency response.